# nuxt using v-show when the user is logged

Tags: javascript, vue.js, authentication, nuxt.js

I need to show in frontend some items depending if the user is logged or not.

```
<div v-if="!this.$store.state.user">
    <button class="btn btn-light me-md-2 m-1" type="button">Login</button>
</div>
<div v-else>
    <button class="btn btn-light me-md-2 m-1" type="button">You logged</button>
</div>
```

This is a small example and it works ok! Except when the user make the auth. He needs to refresh the page and then all items work correctly. More info about the error received is below:

The error "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'user')
An error occurred while rendering the page. Check developer tools console for details.

For me, it is like when the itens are trying to pick the user, the user still empty.

Is there a better way to do that? I tried to use mounted () but the same error comes;

Comment: the error is saying `state` is null, so the template code `state.user` is trying to access a property (user) of null, which can't be done.  a common way around this is to utilize [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) which will prevent reading additional properties following a 'null' property.  try `v-if="!this.$store?.state?.user"`

Comment: Are you using the nuxt auth module? Which version of Nuxt are you using here?